# Maximizing consecutive years or number of countries in panel data with missing data

Tags: r

I have panel data of countries over a time span of 15 years with missing data. I can either maximize the amount of countries I observe by decreasing the number of consecutive years I observe them or I can increase the number of consecutive years at the cost of the number of countries I observe.

For example for the following MRE data, if I were to maximize the number of consecutive years I would observe countries I would have two years from 2002 to 2003 and 6 countries (Country1, Country2, Country4, Country5, Country7 and Country8. If I were to maximize the number of countries at the expense of the number of consecutive years I would observe them, I would actually have two solutions. I could either choose data for year 2003 where only data for Country 3 is missing or I could choose data for year 2005 where only data for Country 2 is missing.

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("Country1", 
"Country2", "Country3", "Country4", "Country5", "Country6", "Country7", 
"Country8", "Country9", "Country10"), class = "factor"), year = c(2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L), x = c(NA, 0.494188331267827, -0.681660478755657, 
-0.652094780680999, -1.28630053043433, 1.68217608051942, -0.177330482269606, 
-0.324270272246319, -0.0568967778473925, NA, -0.635736453948977, 
-0.505957462114257, NA, NA, 0.450187101272656, -0.461644730360566, 
1.34303882517041, -0.588894486259664, NA, -0.018559832714638, 
NA, -0.214579408546869, 0.531496192632572, NA, -0.318068374543844, 
-0.508055079939179, NA, -1.51839408178679, -0.463530401472386, 
-0.929362147453702, NA, -0.100190741213562, 0.306557860789766, 
NA, -1.48746031014148, NA, 0.712666307051405, -1.53644982353759, 
NA, -1.07519229661568, -0.319992868548507, NA, -0.300976126836611, 
NA, 1.00002880371391, NA, NA, -0.528279904445006, 0.0173956196932517, 
-0.621266694796823)), out.attrs = list(dim = c(country = 10L, 
year = 5L), dimnames = list(country = c("country=Country1", "country=Country2", 
"country=Country3", "country=Country4", "country=Country5", "country=Country6", 
"country=Country7", "country=Country8", "country=Country9", "country=Country10"
), year = c("year=2001", "year=2002", "year=2003", "year=2004", 
"year=2005"))), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")

library(panelView)
panelview(data = df, Y = "x", type = "missing", index = c("country", "year"))
```

I am trying to code a solution that allows me to select a balanced panel data set that maximizes either the number of countries (at the expense of the consecutive years) or the number of consecutive time periods (at the expense of number of countries). Thus, I need information for both in a format, i.e. a table, like this:

- Maximizing years: N = 6, T = 2, TRange = 2002-2003
- Maximizing countries: N = 9, T = 1, TRange = 2003 OR 2005

I am stuck to counting the range of years I have observed for each panel id, i.e. country:

```
# Assuming your data frame is df
library(dplyr)
library(panelView)

# Step 1: Identify non-missing years for each country
country_year_ranges <- df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarize(start_year = min(year[!is.na(x)]), end_year = max(year[!is.na(x)])) %>%
  ungroup()

# Step 2: Find the overlap in years across countries
# Create a sequence of years for each country
country_year_seq <- lapply(1:nrow(country_year_ranges), function(i) {
  seq(from = country_year_ranges$start_year[i], 
      to = country_year_ranges$end_year[i])
})

# Find the common years in all sequences
common_years <- Reduce(intersect, country_year_seq)

# Print the results
print(country_year_ranges)
print(common_years)
```

Code to generate a example panel data set with missing values:

```
set.seed(0) # For reproducibility

# Create panel data for 5 countries across 5 years
countries <- paste("Country", 1:10, sep="")
years <- 2001:2005
df <- expand.grid(country = countries, year = years)

# Initialize the variable x with random data
df$x <- rnorm(nrow(df))

# Randomly introduce missing data for 1-4 years for each country
for (country in countries) {
  missing_years_count <- sample(1:2, 1, replace = T)
  missing_years <- sample(years, missing_years_count)
  for (year in missing_years) {
    df$x[df$country == country & df$year == year] <- NA
  }
}

df <- df %>% arrange(country, year) 

df$x <- as.numeric(df$x)

# Visualize the data
panelview(data = df, Y = "x", type = "missing", index = c("country", "year"))
```

Comment: I've read through this a couple times, and I'm not sure what your question is. Seems like you have working code?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read through my problem! The issue is that the code should show me options for N and T as numbers and also specify the year range (2002-2003) when maximizing the countries. Country_year_ranges does show different ranges but not the overlap. In essence, I want to select a balanced panel dataset for my data.

Comment: I have added more information to the problem description.

Comment: Couple questions: where is `panelview()` from (and is it necessary?) I don't think I have whatever package it's from installed. What's with the 2 datasets? You provide code to simulate `df` and provide `dput()` for a second unnamed data frame. They have the same number of rows and columns, but different values and missingness in the `x` column. You don't really talk about differences between them... do we need both of them?

Comment: `panelview` visualizes the missingness of my data quite nicely and is good to get an overview. The package is called `panelView`. I will include it in the code. I created the unnamed data frame with the code above to give a clear example of my problem and the solution I want. `panelview` helps to identify the solution. Using the unnamed data frame is what you need. I will reformat the code.